# java- Full text inverted index defining a word

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am working on a simple full text inverted index trying to build an index of words that I extract from PDF files. I am using PDFBox library to achieve this.

However, I would like to know how does one define a definition of word to index.The way my indexing works is define every word with a space is a word token. For example,

```
This string, is a code.
```

In this case: the index table would contain

```
This
string,
is
a
code.
```

The flaw here is for like `string,` , it comes with a comma where I think `string` would just be sufficient enough because nobody searches `string,` or `code.`

Back to my question, is there a specific rule there I could use to define my word token in a way to prevent this kind of issue with what I have ?

Code:

```
File folder = new File("D:\\PDF1");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (File file : listOfFiles) {
   if (file.isFile()) {
      HashSet<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<>();
      String path = "D:\\PDF1\\" + file.getName();
      try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path))) {    
          if (!document.isEncrypted()) {    
             PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
             String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
             String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
             for(String line : lines) {
                String[] words = line.split(" ");    
                for (String word : words) {
                    uniqueWords.add(word);   
                }

             }                            
          }
       } catch (IOException e) {
         System.err.println("Exception while trying to read pdf document - " + e);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: why don' t you replace `,` with a `""` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat What do you mean? Sorry, I'm a bit blur on this regular expression thing.

Comment: let's see, a word is a `String`, a `String` has a method `replace` - so replace `","` with `""` - this is not regex.  Then add it to your List

Comment: I see but would that contradict some special case like there is a sentence with date 15/12/2018 or f(x) = 2x +3y where it would be ideal to classify these as 2 words considering they are not separated by spaces.

Comment: The logic is yours, in my example **all** I am replacing is `comma`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use replaceAll method to get rid of non-word characters like this:

```
uniqueWords.add(word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));
```

Comment: what is \\W? I am confused

Comment: But there's gonna be a problem say I have a date 10/12/2018 and I have to include this whole in my index then it's gonna omit the "/" which I don't want

Comment: Edited. I added exclusion, you can add exclusions in this section [^/]. So now, it will remove all non-word characters except those which are provided in [^/] section

Comment: There is a problem. If I have **animal.** then i would get **animal** which is fine. But what if I have **69.4** and i would like it in the same form, it would then omit the dot and becomes 694

Comment: So you can check if this is a date or a number.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to remove all punctuation you could do:

```
for(String word : words) {
    uniqueWords.add(word.replaceAll("[.,!?]", ""));
}
```

Which will replace all periods, commas, exclamation marks, and question marks.

---

If you also want to get rid of quotes you can do:

```
uniqueWords.add(word.replaceAll("[.,?!\"]", "")
```

Comment: What does it do? But what if my sentence contains say 11/2/2018 and I would like it as a whole as a word. It would eliminate it right?

Comment: *Which will replace all periods, commas, exclamation marks, and question marks*

Comment: @Daredevil No it will not. Try it for yourself: `System.out.println("10/2/18".replaceAll("[.,!?]", ""));`

Comment: Would it be possible to replace like "animal" to read it as animal?  I tried including it as well but it wouldn't take the argument

Comment: @Daredevil What do you mean? Replace `animal` with what?

Comment: @Daredevil I still don't understand what you mean. You want to extract the text "animal" and have it as an animal? What do you mean by this?

Comment: I mean if the word is string, then we would replace the comma with "" and add it to index as string . That is what your solution proposed correct?  Now if the word is "animal" with double quotes in the PDF files, it would extract and keep in the index as "animal" . Exactly the same correct? So I would rather like it to omit the double quotes and so it just stores the index as **animal** I hope it's clear

Comment: What about the answer proposed by Aleksandr below? It seems it would replace all non word characters , would that be better?

Comment: @Daredevil No this solution would not remove the `""`. To do that you would have to compile it with `replaceAll("[.,?!\"]", "")`

Comment: Okay but there is a downside using replaceAll in specific cases. We will replace words like **string.** so it becomes as **string**. If there is a website in the text like **www.stackoverflow.com** then it's gonna come off as **wwwstackoverflowcom** . There is so much to consider with full text indexing.